# Installing Flask through pip

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python and trying to create web app using Flask. Tried to install the Flask using pip through terminal but I do not See anything happening on the terminal..[image: Kindly check the image which I have attached.]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to install in python shell. Open new command prompt and type `pip install flask`. Or you can exit python shell using CTRL+C and then type the command.

Comment: Sorry but I am adding this in the terminal not in the shell.

Comment: You typed it inside python shell. After you opened terminal you typed python and then typed command. Don't do that. Directly type the command.

Comment: Thanks I have did as well that but I am getting " -bash: pip: command not found"

Comment: If pip is not found then you haven't installed python properly

Comment: I have uninstall python and installing it again...

Comment: I did it again and I found the following error:

Comment: Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Comment: What OS version are you using. What version of python are you trying to install?

Comment: I am using 10.12.6 (macOS Sierra) and I have just installed python 3.7

Comment: Since you are able to install it through pycharm it seems to be a version mismatch issue. Try to use python 3.6 it is much more stable. And use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `python-3.7 -m pip install flask` from your terminal (not from a Python shell)?

Comment: I tried that but it keep showing me an error and now I just installed pycharm and added flask there, it got installed easily there. I am not sure whether I should keep using the Pycharm or I should keep trying until it works on the command prompt.